# Programmatically scrolling on iOS 11 with UISearchController's search bar not disappearing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios11, uisearchcontroller

On iOS 11, where the search bar for is able/recommend to be attached to the navigation controller with `navigationItem.searchController = searchController`, animating a `contentOffset` change seems a little buggy, as the search bar seems to often stay in place. Immediately scrolling afterward fixes it, but it's ugly to see.

If you scroll all the way to the top by tapping the status bar (causing the search bar to be visible), and then animate a `contentOffset` change on the `UIScrollView`, you can see the search bar sticking around sometimes, specifically on device rather than simulator (but you can still see on simulator that the nav bar is too tall):

[image]

This can be observed very easily with even one of Xcode's template projects, such as "Master Detail", by adding a search controller and then adding a button to jump back up.

```swift
@objc func goBackUp(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1200), animated: true)
}
```

Here's an example project showing that: [**Sample Project**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ZzAMgSlvKdb7FJWNzjNGv712-Ci59Oj/view?usp=sharing)

I'm aware this is most likely an iOS bug as there's no issue on iOS 10 and earlier, but does anyone know of a fix in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

There's a new searchController property on navigationItem in iOS 11.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller

On iOS 11, if you don't set navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false, the search bar may initially be hidden, unless the user scrolls down to reveal it. If you do set it to false, it appears stacked below where the title would go without the user having to scroll.

Comment: That property just affects whether or not it sticks when scrolling. The issue outlined above is that when scrolling and it's set not to stick, it does.